# how to count repeat dates using proc sql

Tags: sas, proc-sql

I have a dataset as such:

```
    Pat_ID  Date        Prov_ID
    A       05/12/2012  X1
    A       05/12/2012  X2
    B       11/12/2012  X1
    B       03/22/2012  X1
    C       04/25/2012  X1
    C       04/25/2012  X2
    C       04/25/2012  X3
    ...
```

As can be seen, some patients have the same date but different providers and some have diff dates but the same provider. How can I use proc sql to count by Pat_ID and Date such that it would give something like this:

```
Pat_ID  Date       Count
A       05/12/2012 2
B       11/12/2012 1
B       03/22/2012 1
C       04/25/2012 3
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
SELECT Pat_ID, Date, COUNT(Prov_ID)
FROM your_table
GROUP BY Pat_ID, Date
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
select Pat_ID, Date, count( Prov_ID ) as Count from ReplaceThisWithYourTablesName group by Pat_ID, Date order by Pat_ID asc, Date desc
```

You didn't specify the table name so you'll have to fix that yourself.

Important part is to list both columns in the group by in the order of most importance.